# Adding a Ternary Switch to a Button - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a little script that toggles the visibility of a text element. With each time the element becomes visible, the color of it changes from either blue to red or from red to blue.

I now want the text to change between THREE different colors (red, blue, green) in a specific order (red, blue, green, red, blue, green, red, ...), but am confused as how to approach this.

I've tried implementing a third number to do a modulus check against, but doing so did not yeild the results I was looking for, so my question is thus: Is there a method out there for implementing a ternary switch?

I'm not looking for any one answer, but more a push in the right direction. Currently I'm stumped.

The code is as follows:

```
var visible = false;
var hiddenCount = 0;
var pElement = document.getElementById("testVisibility");
function showElement() { 
    if ( visible = !visible ) {
        if ( hiddenCount % 4 == 0 ) {
            pElement.style.color = "red";
        } else if ( hiddenCount % 2 == 0 ) {
            pElement.style.color = "blue";
        }
        pElement.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        pElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    hiddenCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to put the colors in an Array, and maintain a counter that increments as needed. Then use the counter to get an index from the Array.

You can use the modulus operator to make the index never exceed the top index of the array.

```
var visible = false;
var hiddenCount = 0;
var pElement = document.getElementById("testVisibility");
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]

function showElement() { 
    if ((visible = !visible)) { // Use the modulus to get index
        pElement.style.color = colors[hiddenCount % colors.length];
        pElement.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        pElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    hiddenCount++;
}
```

I kept the `hiddenCount` at the bottom where you had it, though it always increments, even when hiding. If you always want to see the next color when showing, then move the increment to the `if` statement.